# Number picker start changing value for few seconds

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like a numberpicker to start changing the values automaticly for few seconds .

```
   private void changeValueByOne(final NumberPicker higherPicker, final boolean increment) {

    Method method;
    try {
        // refelction call for
        // higherPicker.changeValueByOne(true);
        method = higherPicker.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("changeValueByOne", boolean.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(higherPicker, increment);

    } catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I ve implemented this method and tried

```
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    changeValueByOne(wp,true);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

But it is not ok .

I would like to have an effect as a slot machine .

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you simply set the value to an incremented value? Something like this:

```
private void changeValueByOne(final NumberPicker higherPicker) {
   int oldValue = higherPicker.getValue();
   higherPicker.setValue(oldValue++);
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the source of the method you're reflecting:

```
private void changeValueByOne(boolean increment) {
    if (mHasSelectorWheel) {
        mInputText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (!moveToFinalScrollerPosition(mFlingScroller)) {
            moveToFinalScrollerPosition(mAdjustScroller);
        }
        mPreviousScrollerY = 0;
        if (increment) {
            mFlingScroller.startScroll(0, 0, 0, -mSelectorElementHeight, SNAP_SCROLL_DURATION);
        } else {
            mFlingScroller.startScroll(0, 0, 0, mSelectorElementHeight, SNAP_SCROLL_DURATION);
        }
        invalidate();
    } else {
        if (increment) {
            setValueInternal(mValue + 1, true);
        } else {
            setValueInternal(mValue - 1, true);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that if `mHasSelectorWheel = true`, it calls the startScroll method. In other words, it sounds like your NumberPicker has `mHasSelectorWheel = false`, in which case you're out of luck given your current implementation. It is highly advisable that you look into a custom scrollable number picker widget.

Comment: I don t think I will have animated effect , I want to have an effect like you scroll in the list .with set value it will just set witout animation

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions, or does the code run fine? Reflection can be tricky...you may want to consider finding a custom number picker widget (or copying the Android source and modifying it yourself)

Comment: i don t get exceptions , i just when i do set value to have an animation , to be seen like you scroll to that value , with my code it just comes instantly that value . I want an effect like a slot machine . Press a button and number pickers start rolling by themselves .